# C++17 can variadic template class define new type and variadic data member?

Tags: c++, class, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T0, typename T1>
struct Clazz {
    void doSomething(const std::shared_ptr<T0>& p0,
            const std::shared_ptr<T1>& p1) {}
    T0 t0;
    T1 t1;
};
template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
struct Clazz3 {
    void doSomething(const std::shared_ptr<T0>& p0,
            const std::shared_ptr<T1>& p1,
            const std::shared_ptr<T1>& p2) {}
    T0 t0;
    T1 t1;
    T2 t1;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct ClazzN {
    // Q1: one part: define types in doSomething
    // Q2: two part: define data members
    // using param_type = typename (std::shared_ptr<Ts>, ...) // fold expression? can it works on type part, or only value?

    // Ts... ts; // ??? pack it by tuple ???
};

int main() {
    Clazz<int, double> c2;
    Clazz3<int, double, char> c3;

    return 0;
}
```

I have a class `ClazN`, and I:

1. want a variadic template form, instead of limiting the class template type size.
2. want define different data members as the template type correspodingly.
3. the `T1`, `T2` ... `Tn` have no relationship.

How to write `ClazzN`? It's too stupid to write a lot repeated codes.

How could I do this? Need your help, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: "pack it by tuple ???" why not? Did you try to have a `std::tuple<Ts...>` member?

Comment: It's all right for me, only if it works. You can ommit my comments. I comment because I don not know how to do it.

Comment: "it works" is not a useful description for an objective. Have you tried it? Does it fulfils your expectations?

Comment: when you have code that has an error, then you better show that code and the error message. I posted an answer, but I don't know if this really adresses the issue in your acutal code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::tuple`, also for the `param_type`. In case you want a tuple of shared pointers, that is:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename... Ts>
struct Clazz {
    using param_type = typename std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Ts>...>; 
    std::tuple<Ts...> ts;
};

int main() {
    Clazz<int, double> c0;
}
```

Comment: Great! But how can I use the paramers seperatedly in function `doSomething` as you shows:
void doSomething(param_type params) {
    // use every params at any will
}

Comment: @xishvai whats the problem with `void doSomething(param_type params)` ?

Comment: It compiles ok(includes the doSomething part). But I don not know how to get each parameter's type and value? How can i make it?

Comment: @xishvai if you want to know how to deal with `std::tuple` you can open another question

Comment: I think your answer solved my problem. Thanks a lot !!! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) to access the list of types:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <typename... Ts>
struct Clazz {
    template<std::size_t I>
    using T = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
};


using Test = Clazz<int, int&, double, std::string>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Test::T<0>, int>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Test::T<1>, int&>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Test::T<2>, double>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Test::T<3>, std::string>, "");
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dvadxrbEM